# jqplot show trendline over barchart

Tags: jqplot, bar-chart, trendline

Can anyone please tell me what I need to do with the code below to display a trendline over my barchart. Thanks!

I am using the JqPlot plugin. Here's the code to date...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.jqplot.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var planned = [70000,90000,120000,100000,];
        var actual = [80000,80000,150000,120000];
        var xAxis = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'];
        $(function() {  
            $.jqplot('chartDiv', [planned, actual], BarChart());
        });


        function BarChart()
        {
            var optionsObj = {
                title: 'Departmental Savings',
                axes: {
                     xaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                        ticks: xAxis,                       
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        tickOptions: { showMark: false, formatString: "%d" },                       
                    },
                },

            grid: {
                    borderColor: "#fff",
                    background: "#FFF",
                    drawGridlines: false,
                    shadow: false
                }, 

                series: [
                    {label:'Planned'},
                    {label: 'Actual'}
                    ],

                legend: {
                    show: true,
                    location: 'sw',
                    xoffset: -70,
                    yoffset: -22,
                    },

                seriesDefaults:{
                    shadow: false,
                    renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    rendererOptions:{
                       barPadding: 0,
                       barMargin: 10,
                       barWidth: 25,
                   }

                },  
            };
            return optionsObj;
        }


    </script>

</head>

<body>

<div>
     <div id="chartDiv" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I have a bit of work still to do! The top image is where I am currently, The bottom one is what it will hopefully look like when i'm done!

The fluff around the edges is simple CSS stuff!

[image]

Comment: what does your trend line represent?  From your example plot it looks like the mid point of Planned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example where the "trend-line" is the mean of the planned and actual, plotted as a line over the bar graph:

[image]

All I did was add a third series with the trend data.  In the series options I set the "renderer" to bar for the two bar series, leaving the third to be the default line.  Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/aH6Qc/1/) (you have to cache the JS files since jqplot does not allow hotlinking).

```
    var planned = [70000,90000,120000,100000,];
    var actual = [80000,80000,150000,120000];
    var trend = [75000, 85000, 140000, 110000];
    var xAxis = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'];

    $(function() {  
        $.jqplot('chart1', [planned, actual, trend], BarChart());
    });


    function BarChart()
    {
        var optionsObj = {
            title: 'Departmental Savings',
            axes: {
                 xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks: xAxis,                       
                },
                yaxis: {
                    tickOptions: { showMark: false, formatString: "%d" },                       
                },
            },

            grid: {
                borderColor: "#fff",
                background: "#FFF",
                drawGridlines: false,
                shadow: false
            }, 

            series: [
                {label:'Planned',renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer},
                {label: 'Actual',renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer},
                {label: 'Mean of Planned and Actual'}
                ],

            legend: {
                show: true,
                location: 'nw'
                },

            seriesDefaults:{
                shadow: false,

                rendererOptions:{
                   barPadding: 0,
                   barMargin: 10,
                   barWidth: 25,
               }

            },  
        };
        return optionsObj;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mark, fantastic! Thanks for the guidance! Managed to get it looking more or less the same as the screenshot... cheers!

Comment: Hi again Mark! Maybe you can help! I am trying to limit the number  of point labels that display in the grid! Maybe you know how? thanks for all you help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807451/jqplot-limiting-point-labels-displayed-to-just-1-series